# What version of J2EE am I using on my AWS Elastic BeanStalk Tomcat 6 server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to know what version of j2ee I am running on my elastic beanstalk instance but I do not know where to look for it.

I am using ami-2537f14c running 32bit tomcat 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) is a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) 2.5 container. Servlet 2.5 is part of Java EE 5. But Tomcat is actually not a full fledged Java EE application server. It's just a simple JSP/Servlet container. The full fledged Java EE 5 application servers are JBoss AS 4.2, 5.x, Glassfish v2, etc. They bundles JSF, EJB, JMS, etc as well.

Please note that "J2EE" refers to the old J2EE 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4. Since Java EE 5 (May 2006), it's renamed to "Java EE". Be careful to call it rightly. See also [Wikipedia: Java EE version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history).